# How to display the different php tables given an item from php combobox?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, combobox

I have different queries that I recover and I want to display each query in php table when an item is selected in the combobox
For example if I do click in the first item below should display the corresponding table given  the query that this contains, this if is possible using ajax or als in other page
I was trying to do with jquery but I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you are getting at, your jquery would be written so on the select change send off a get request to the page that gets the data e.g.

```
$.get("data.php?query=2", function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

I would advise not sending the actual query from the select because it can leave you open for SQL injection. If you have a key for each item then that key would correspond in the data.php file.